# which data was saved in table session Magento 2?

Tags: magento2.4, session

I configured session that would be saved to database in file **app/etc/env.php**. Now, table session has expanded to large size (~4GB). I want to open my mind which data that Magento saved in table session? Can I modify data before save it to database (remove some default data and add new custom data)?

Answer (score 0):

**Database** to store user session data in the database. Choose database storage if you have a clustered database; otherwise, there might not be much benefit over file-based storage.

**session** is table name for session storage. 
Its better to use the **redis** for entire session storage. 
session table structure as,
[image]